# How to prevent functional component's re-rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

I am developing an application using React Js and Framer Motion animation library. But every time the state changes, the element in the functional component is rendered again and the animation plays again. Even though I used useMemo, I could not prevent the animation from playing again. How can I solve this situation. I prepared a simple example to express the problem. I would appreciate if you can help.

Here is my codes;

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { jsonData } from './data';

function App() {
  const [stateChange, setStateChange] = useState(false);
  const [isViewFirstLoad, setViewFirstLoad] = useState(false);

  const IconList = React.memo(({ data }) => {
    return (
      data.map((oItem, oIndex) => {
        return (
          <motion.div
            key={oIndex}
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1, ease: "easeOut" }}
            data-id={oItem.id}
            className='item-container'>
            <img src={oItem.thumbnail} />
            <div className='content'>
              <p>{oItem.title}</p>
              <p>{oItem.description}</p>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        )
      })
    )
  }, [isViewFirstLoad]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setViewFirstLoad(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className='fixed-header'>
        <button onClick={() => { setStateChange(!stateChange) }}>Toggle State</button>
    <p>
      CHANGE STATUS: <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{stateChange.toString()}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div className='fluid-container'>
    <IconList data={jsonData} />
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are generating a new `IconList` component on each render. Move the `IconList` out of the `App` component.

Comment: Thank you for the information, @OriDrori. Can't we use the IconList component in the App component and control it with useMemo?

Comment: Nope. Whenever that state changes you get a new component.